# PHP shorthand if can't be combined with echo as one of the option?

Tags: php, echo, conditional-operator, isset

This is a line inside the signup form which will pass the value entered via POST to a class called 'user' on success. On failure I want it to echo a failure message.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))?$user->email=$_POST['email']:echo "no value found";
```

following is the error

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '?' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\login_API\Users\signup.php** on line
>   **15**

Comment: That is more a mashup of an if and a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is a statement, not an expression, it can't be used as part of another expression.

You should use an ordinary `if` statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $user->email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    echo "no value found";
}
```

Stylistically, you should only use a ternary expression if you're using the result of it somewhere, e.g.

```
$user->email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "default@example.com";
```

Don't use it as a general replacement for `if`.